# FLEX - Image Upload

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I would like to know if there's a way to see an image on the Web browser on a FLEX application but not uploading it first to the web server but just doing something like a buffer or something on FLEX, ActionScript, or Flash.

Sounds weird but there has to be a way...

Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to display an image from a URL straight into flex ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FileReference class.  Have a look on http://sherifabdou.com/2008/06/using-the-new-filereference-class-in-flex-to-save-and-load-without-a-server/

Comment: Just what I was looking for,,, I will give it a try and if it works you got my vote dude. Thanks!!